# Postgresql - inserting blank into timestamp field

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert a blank into a timestamp field. In the table, it is defined as `updt_ts timestamp NULL`. But, I am still getting the below error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY dt_acct_stat_dim, line 1, column updt_ts: ""
```

Any fix for this error?

Comment: When you say "blank", do you mean NULL, or an empty string? Because for a field of type `TIMESTAMP`, the first should work (if the field is nullable), but the second won't. Are you running this query manually, or getting the input from somewhere (that might be sending empty string)?

Comment: Show us your insert statement. But try `INSERT VALUES(id, NULL)` instead of `INSERT VALUES(id, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your error message, you're using the `copy` command.

When using the `copy` command, one of the options available to you is to specify a null string:

```
copy
    table_name
from
    '/my/file.csv'
with (
    format csv,
    null ''
);
```

[Full docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)